# Assigning output name based on c++ header file and cmake command

Tags: c++, cmake, versioning, conditional-compilation

I have a C++ project as following structure:

```
MyProject
 - app
   - version.hpp
   - appmodule.cpp
   - appmodule.cpp
   - main.cpp
 - CMakeLists.txt
```

And the version is defined in `version.hpp`:

```cpp
// version.hpp

#define VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define VERSION_MINOR 100
#define VERSION_INTERNAL 71
```

In order to generate output filename with version info, I add following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

file(READ "app/version.hpp" ver)

string(REGEX MATCH "VERSION_MAJOR ([0-9]*)" _ ${ver})
set(VERSION_MAJOR ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
string(REGEX MATCH "VERSION_MINOR ([0-9]*)" _ ${ver})
set(VERSION_MINOR ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
string(REGEX MATCH "VERSION_INTERNAL ([0-9]*)" _ ${ver})
set(VERSION_INTERNAL ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})

set(MY_PROJECT_APP app_v${VERSION_MAJOR}_${VERSION_MINOR}_${VERSION_INTERNAL})
add_executable(${MY_PROJECT_APP} app/main.cpp)
```

To build the project, I run

```sh
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

The output is `app_v1_100_71` based on the above example.

However, now I want to change the version number based on the arguments passed by compiler.

Therefore, I changed the `version.hpp` like this:

```cpp
// version.hpp (specify different version based at compile time)

#if defined(BUILD_QA_TEST)
#define VERSION_MAJOR 0
#elif defined(BUILD_STAGE)
#define VERSION_MAJOR 1
#else
#define VERSION_MAJOR 2
#endif

#define VERSION_MINOR 100
#define VERSION_INTERNAL 71
```

In this way, the original `string(REGEX MATCH "VERSION_MAJOR ([0-9]*)" _ ${ver})`
is no longer applicable because it cannot parse C macro.

Is there any method to identify which `VERSION_MAJOR` should be use for cmake?

Furthermore, is there any better way for versioning this project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend doing it the other way around and "transforming" the version information from cmake to C++ - not the other way around.

You can use cmake's [`configure_file`()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) function to substitute the version variables in your C++ code with information originating from cmake (eg. the `project VERSION`).

You may at then simply use [`OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html?highlight=output_name) to build the output file name from your cmake version variable(s).

Comment: Will certainly work unless a multi configuration is used that includes the qa version as its own configuration....